# Accessing a SQL Server from a Windows service running on a domain user

Tags: sql-server, service

**If I run the Windows service using the Local System account, I have no problems at all.**

The service was developed using C#.NET. The connection string is like this:

> "Data Source={0};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Async=true;Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}"

If I run the service using a domain user, I get the error below when trying the connection to the SQL Server. (The service generates an error log where I can see what´s happening). I´m aware of the typical causes for this error, like enabling remote connection, protocol configuration and firewall. But the error occurs even running the SQL Server in the the same machine the service is running and only if I don´t run the service with the Local System account.

> .Net SqlClient Data Provider - A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)

Even if I set the account as a local administrator I get the error.

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: and does the domain user have access using Management Studio? seems like your user, even administrator doesn't have permission or dont exist in the sql server. I had a problem like that: another person installed sql server in my machine and he didn't configured users during installation.

Comment: The thing is the connection string doesn't appear to use windows authentication, it uses SQL authentication so the windows user should be mostly irrelelvant

Comment: The error says the SQL server is not accessible. It's the usual error for connectivity problems. The problem is that it only happens when using the domain user, regardless its permissions at the SQL Server...